# JavaScript Regular Expression for Money non JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, regex, mask

I need a money mask for an input, the problem is that I can't use jquery on my application.

How can I do this using regular expression 'on key up' for example?

here is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        money:
            <input type="text" class="money"  maxlength="22" id="money" name="money">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I the format to look like like `00.000,00`

Comment: When I read the title I thought you are offering money for a solution, oh well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

There is a problem with trying to validate text as it's being typed which can be illustrated with this http://jsfiddle.net/denomales/dgeH2/. As the text field is updated if the current string matches or not will be displayed directly below.

- `^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{3})*(?:\,[0-9]{2})?$` will match currency in the format 00.000,00 as requested in the comments

[image]

- `^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$` will match currency in the format 00,000.00

[image]

Comment: @Philippe really sorry i forgot to put the format! but it would be like **00.000,00**

Comment: Sorry about that, please see completely overhauled answer and included jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/denomales/dgeH2/.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to give you a direct answer since you didn't provide the format...

The JavaScript way of testing a regex on a string is:

```
function regexmoney(){
    var patt=new RegExp(pattern,modifiers);
    var string = document.getElementById('money').value;
    var result = patt.test(string);//Returns true/false
    if(!result){
         var charArray=string.split();
         //Iterate through the array and arrange the chars as 
         //you see fit (returning moneyresult)
         document.getElementById('money').value = moneyresult;
    }
}
```

Then the HTML:

```
<tr>
<td>
    money:
        <input type="text" onkeyup="regexmoney()" class="money"  maxlength="22" id="money" name="money">
    </td>
</tr>
```

And to generate the regex http://txt2re.com/

Hope this helps...

Comment: You commented on the wrong answer and I already gave you the tools to do this yourself, try to figure it out on your own.